# Cross compilation for openwrt : mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: cannot find -ljpeg

Tags: c, linux, mips, cross-compiling, libjpeg

I'm using ubuntu 14.12 and I'm trying to cross compile a C program 
The goal of this program is to use the webcam and record images,to do so I used `libjpeg`.

when compiling the program an error occurs `mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: cannot find -ljpeg`

For cross-compilation I'm using

```
mips-openwrt-linux-gcc -std=c99 catch.c -I ~/crosscompilation/openwrt/build_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/jpeg-6b/ -L ~/crosscompilation/openwrt/build_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/ -Wl,-rpath-link=~/crosscompilation/openwrt/build_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/ -ljpeg -o catch
```

`catch.c` is the Code file and `~/crosscompilation/openwrt/` is my toolchain directory

How to fix this ?

Comment: Install `libjpeg` and `libjpeg-dev`? :)

Comment: already installed

Comment: Under `~/crosscompilation` tree too?

Comment: under ~/crosscompilation/openwrt/

Comment: Also, looking at your include path, `-l` might need some other name in this case than the generic `-ljpeg` what's the `.so` file name?

Comment: I coudn't find the `.so` file

Comment: Then you haven't installed the lib, hence the error.

Comment: So how to do it for openWRT (my distribution target for cross-compilation)